# VS 2017 Publish web app fails due to access denied 1st time but succeed 2nd time

Tags: windows, visual-studio, iis, asp.net-core, permissions

Windows server 2016, VS 2017, asp.net core web app

When publishing to a File folder on a test server, I often get access denied errors when publish attempts to delete the existing files before copying over the new files.

The strange thing is that if I immediately follow up with another attempt to publish, it works fine.  I don't think its a permission issue, since my account is in the local admin group on the test server.

I think it may be an issue where the IIS App pool may need to be stopped before publishing.  Haven't tried that yet, but that wouldn't really explain why the publish succeeds the 2nd time.  What can I check?

Comment: Do you simply replace all the files or you try to delete old files in the first place?

Comment: In the options for the publish profile, there is a checkbox for "Delete all existing files prior to publish" and I have that selected.